# How can I change/add google-services.json search location

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

Now Google Services Plugins trying to find it in two dirs:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':krq-player-android:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
  C:\Users\Alexandr\Projects\krq\krq-player-android\src\debug\google-services.json
  C:\Users\Alexandr\Projects\krq\krq-player-android\google-services.json
```

How can I add one more during the build time?

Comment: Any news on how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You have place the json file in wrong location

The location is project/app/google-services.json

Comment: Yes, and I want to make this location correct via adding to some kind of 'search list'